# Evil ctypes hack in python

Tags: python, ctypes, low-level

I'd like to start by saying that this question is asked purely out of interest, and I by no means intend to use something so incredibly evil in any serious project. (yes, it's that kind of a question)

I've been trying to piece together some information in the inner workings of CPython, and as far as I've been able to work out, it should be possible to manipulate the actual values for small ints, so that (for instance) 1 + 2 could evaluate to something other than 3. I'm hardly on expert on this kind of low-level hacking, and all i've been able to achieve is segfaults. This is what I've got so far:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.c_int8.from_address(id(1) + 8).value = 2
```

I was under the impression that that would do the trick, but this just causes any statement that tries to evaluate 1 to blow up with a segfault. While that was an amusing achievement, that was hardly what I was looking for. Am I missing something? Could it be that the c_int8 and the + 8 in that line only work on certain platforms? I'd happily look this up if I knew exactly what to look for, though I'd imagine the answer might hide somewhere in the CPython source.

Comment: Isn't value be read-only?

Comment: Well, value can definately be written to, I know that much. If I try to set it, and then read the .value again using the same syntax, I do get the new value... and the segfault only appears when I actually try to directly use the number 1. So, it clearly managed to change something ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`8` would be "correct" on a 32-bit platform where `ob_refcnt` and `ob_type` are 4 bytes each; on a 64-bit platform this will be different.  Essentially you're trying to go past `PyObject_HEAD` to the rest of the integer object, so try checking the size of `PyObject` in a compiler or debugger.

Obviously this will be different on Python 3, where there is only the `long` type so even small integers are variable-length; in that case you'll want `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` (and `PyVarObject`) instead of `PyObject_HEAD`.

A good place to start looking at this is the documentation inside [`object.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Include/object.h), also readable in the C API reference manual at https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html, and then at [`intobject.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Include/intobject.h), or [`longintrepr.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Include/longintrepr.h) for Python 3.

---

Note: changing the value of `1` will still segfault, but for different reasons.  Changing the value of a larger small integer such as `10` should be safe, though.

Comment: That sounds like exactly the info i was looking for :) thanks! I won't be able to test it out until later today, but I will accept and expand on the answer later when I do get it working.

Comment: This won't work in general, even in 2.x with a correctly defined `PyIntObject` struct that ensures the correct offset and data type. There are countless references to these small integers in Python code and the interpreter implementation, and you'll without doubt trigger a segfault if you try to modify `int(1)`. Look for a small integer with no existing references, such as `PyIntObject.from_address(id(251)).ob_ival = 1000; 251 + 1 == 1001`.

Comment: For 'fun' you can run Python under a debugger to trace the crashes. If you modify `int(10)`, try `exec '["a","b","c","d","e", "f","g","h","i","j"]'`, which shifts `None` out to the code object's `co_consts[10]`. The compiler uses a dict of constants, so this may crash in [`dict_keys_inorder`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f89216059edf/Python/compile.c#l3779) or [`listextend`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f89216059edf/Objects/listobject.c#l798) when [`makecode`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f89216059edf/Python/compile.c#l3839) tries to sequence the constants as a list.

Comment: @eryksun yup, that's what I got :) - seems the issue is that `PyDict_Next` gives you the ordinal as a Python integer, so when it tries to use that it has the wrong value.  Might be fun to swap `4` and `5` though.

Comment: Yes, the ordinal stored in the dict is an `int`. So if you change `int(10)` to a large value you'll probably get the segfault in `dict_keys_inorder`, since `PyTuple_SET_ITEM` tries to write at an unallocated address. A smaller value (e.g. 100) may not segfault. But now the `PyObject *` at index 10 is random garbage. When `listextend` tries to do a `Py_INCREF` on it, you'll get a segfault there.