# CPython's PyLong_FromLong(0L) never fails?

Tags: python, error-handling, python-c-api

This piece of code is from the [Python C-API reference](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#exceptions):

```c
item = PyLong_FromLong(0L);
if (item == NULL)
    goto error;
```

Assuming the interpreter is CPython, the memory for the Python `0` object is [already allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36898917/3067276), so what could go wrong there? Reading the source code for `PyLong_FromLong`, for small-integer values it would [immediately return](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a4ba8a3983356fceb4aedabe0c338180666a79aa/Objects/longobject.c#L305) `get_small_int((sdigit)0L)`. The `get_small_int` function is really [very simple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a4ba8a3983356fceb4aedabe0c338180666a79aa/Objects/longobject.c#L39):

```c
static PyObject *
get_small_int(sdigit ival)
{
    assert(IS_SMALL_INT(ival));
    PyThreadState *tstate = _PyThreadState_GET();
    PyObject *v = (PyObject*)tstate->interp->small_ints[ival + NSMALLNEGINTS];
    Py_INCREF(v);
    return v;
}
```

The assertion on the first line won't fail because `PyLong_FromLong` already verified it. `_PyThreadState_GET()` is a macro that, according to a [comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a4ba8a3983356fceb4aedabe0c338180666a79aa/Include/internal/pycore_pystate.h#L297) next to its definition, `is unsafe: it does not check for error and it can return NULL.` This might look like a source of failure but **note that `tstate->interp` is accessed normally**, which would segfault the interpreter if the macro had returned `NULL`. After that, the wanted reference to the Python `0` object is `Py_INCREF`'d and returned to the original caller of `PyLong_FromLong(0L)`.

Did I understant correctly that CPython's `PyLong_FromLong` can't fail for small-integer arguments, or did I miss something? Also, just for completeness, can extension modules written in C can be used from other interpreters, or when writing them I can assume that they will be dealing with CPython?

Comment: Oh it may be trivial to [make this assumption fail with `ctypes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060991/evil-ctypes-hack-in-python).  The question mentions 32-bit platforms, but on a Python 3 interpreter running on a 64-bit platform you may try something like `ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(1) + 24).value = 2` to manipulate the underlying value of `1`, and then do `1 == 2` and the interpreter may segfault.

Comment: Nice, though this is something I would definitely assume that didn't happen hehehe.

Comment: PyPy attempts to define a C API compatibility layer (as does Jython I think) so the assumption that you're always dealing with CPython may not be true. But may still be a reasonable assumption to take anyway. I think I'd just a bit wary of writing code based on exactly what is considered a "small integer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right, there would never be any erro here, the small ints are preallocated, so `PyLong_FromLong(0L);` never fails.

But why still test if *item* was a *NULL*? As I see, this just follows a partten:

- new an PyLongObject;
- then test if successed.

The *PyLong_FromLong* does some optomization by caching small ints, but it still returns a New Object mostly and logicaly, though *0L* does not. And as we a function caller we should not rely on the inner cache strtegy. So leave some code to check would make sense and safer.